# Switch Style Issue in MAUI

Tags: maui, switchcontrol

I'm using a switch on my MAUI project. I found a style issue on Android devices 10 and 11, but on Android 12, there is no style issue.

Below is the screenshot on the Android 10 and Android 11.

[image]

Below is the screenshot on the Android 12.

[image]

Code:

```
 <Switch
    x:Name="sms_switch"
    ThumbColor="#5abcd7"
    OnColor="#5abcd7"
    Toggled="SMSToggledEvent"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of way to fix this UI issue but didn't get any solution. Finally I used switch on and off icons and resolved.

This is not a solution but a way to fix the UI issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I created two new projects to test your code.

1. In the target .net 7.0 project: all of the Android 10 , Android 11 and Android 12 device can have the correct style.
2. In the target .net 8.0 project: all the versions of android device had the default style.

I used Visual Studio version 17.9.0 Preview 1.1.

In addition, I found the similar issue on the github: [Switch thumbcolor cannot be set in code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18625) and [Switch on Android has wrong initial color](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18506). You can follow up them.

Comment: Also, in target .net 7.0, I'm facing the same issue. On Android 12, it is working fine, but on Android 10 and 11 (Oneplus 6 ), it is not. I'm using Visual Studio version 17.9.0 Preview 1.1.

Comment: But I tested on the Android 10 and 11 emulator and it worked well. I also use Visual Studio version 17.9.0 Preview 1.1. @MatthewPans

Comment: Could you please check it on a real device?

Comment: I tested on Goolge Pixl Android 10 and Redmi Android 13 devices. Both of them worked fine. @MatthewPans

Comment: I faced this issue on Oneplus 6 , Android 11 and OPPO A9 2020 Android Version 11

Comment: I have no phycial devices with Android 11. You can report this on the repo. @MatthewPans